# Remove zeros from multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with `ID`, `Numerator` and `Denominator` columns.

How would I go about removing zeros when present in the same row for numerator and denominator?

I'm thinking I can do a case when statement, for example, case when Numerator = '0' and Denominator = '0' then remove, but my syntax is off.

Input table example

```
ID Numerator Denominator
------------------------
1      1         0
2      0         0
```

Output table example:

```
ID Numerator Denominator
------------------------
1      1         0
2                          <--- In SQL Server, it would possibly show up as NULL since it is blank data.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use two case expressions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when numerator <> 0 or denominator <> 0 then numerator end) as new_numerator,
       (case when numerator <> 0 or denominator <> 0 then denominator end) as new_denominator
from t;
```